# SFDX FLS Change on Profile deletes other permissions

Tags: salesforcedx

We are facing some strange behaviour with changes done on profiles, here is the scenario:

We pushed entire metadata to the scratch org and ensured there are no changes detected when we ran sfdx force:source:status command.

1. Change the field level security for one field on the System Administrator profile.
2. Run sfdx force:source:status command, which shows that the System Administrator profile has been changed remote.
3. Then we pull the profile using sfdx force:source:pull command, which pulls the changed profile in the local file system.
4. Expected change in the profile:

Changed values only for the  and  nodes for the field which we changed FLS.

5. The actual change in the profile:

Loads of `<classAccess>` nodes got deleted from the profile, which existed prior to pulling. When investigated on the scratch org for the same profile and the class, the permissions were there on the profile.

Loads of `<applicationVisibilities>` nodes got deleted from the profile, which existed prior to pulling. Although the same exists in the Scratch org when opened up the profile.

Loads of `<recordTypeVisibilties>` nodes got deleted from the profile, which existed prior to pulling. Although the same exists in the Scratch org when opened up the profile.

Is this a bug or are we missing something?

Appreciate any feedback.

Thanks